# laying 3 divs but having extra blank space

Tags: html, css

I have an project that includes 3 divs to be layered on top of each other using the z index in css, but when I apply that to the three and adjust the top positioning, theres a big empty space left where the two other div were previously. Anyone come across this and figured out how to resolve it?

Heres the html

```
<div id="kit" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HI 9829 Kit</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="kit edgeLoad-EDGE-1809939789" style="margin: auto;"></div>

    <div class="container edgeLoad-EDGE-1809939789"></div>

    <div class="buttons edgeLoad-EDGE-1809939789">
        <a href="#a1" class="dot edgeLoad-EDGE-1809939789" style="top: 138px; left: 28px"></a>
        <a href="#a18" class="dot edgeLoad-EDGE-1809939789" style="top: 45px; left: 261px"></a>
    </div>

      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
          <h3>©2013</h3>
      </div>
 </div>
```

and heres the css

```
#kit .kit{
    width:700px;
    height:670px;
    background-image:url(../img/9829-Kit_2.png);
    z-index:1;
}   

#kit .buttons{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 670px;
    width: 700px;
    z-index:3;
}

#kit .container {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url(../img/9829-Kit.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 670px;
    width: 700px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: a fiddle of this would help reproducing the problem.

Comment: This examples does not render as described.

Comment: Hint: you should use position ABSOLUTE, not relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the z-index to operate properly, position attribute should be set, nevermind if it is set to absolute, relative, or fixed.

Comment: Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed), source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V7vTk/

heres a fiddle of the project. keep in mind, that the div with the class of "buttons" needs to be relative so my a tags(which act as buttons and are absolute postioned) will function.